# Actualizar foto y borrar la anterior laravel

Tags: laravel

actualmente estoy creando un formulario de actualizacion de registro de usuario (datos personales y foto) y al momento de que actualizo los datos del usuario todo se actualiza correctamente pero el problema es que cuando se actualiza la foto del usuario se guarda una nueva en la carpeta storage/public pero la foto anterior se sigue quedando dentro de la carpeta...como hacer para borrar la foto anterior??

Mi codigo:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        $trabajador=Trabajador::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('update', $trabajador);
        if($request->hasFile('foto')){
            $trabajador->foto=\Storage::putFile('public', $request->file('foto'));
        }
        $trabajador->update($request->only('nombre','correo'));
        $trabajador->roles()->sync($request->roles);
        return back()->with('info', 'Usuario Actualizado');              
    }
```

Como borrar la anterior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $trabajador=Trabajador::findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize('update', $trabajador);
    if($request->hasFile('foto')){
        // aquí compruebo que exista la foto anterior
        if (\Storage::exists($trabajador->foto))
        {
             // aquí la borro
             \Storage::delete($trabajador->foto);
        }
        $trabajador->foto=\Storage::putFile('public', $request->file('foto'));
    }
    $trabajador->update($request->only('nombre','correo'));
    $trabajador->roles()->sync($request->roles);
    return back()->with('info', 'Usuario Actualizado');              
}
```

Comment: Gracias man! Justo era lo que buscaba! (y)

Answer (score -1):

Una opción es ponerle como nombre del archivo el id del usuario (para que no se repita), sino lo quieres tan corto lo concatenas con el nombre o algún otro dato que sea fijo, ejemplo el DNI... Y al actualizar sobreescribes el archivo.

Luego para leer el dato haces la consulta correspondiente.