# Ruta de archivo incorrecta

Tags: php, laravel, update, fileupload

Quiero borrar la imagen de perfil que tenga en mi carpeta de `profiles` cuando decida actualizar la foto desde el formulario en el front-end. La manera en la que estoy procesando el archivo es a través de un condicional if, en donde busco si en la solicitud existe algo para la columna de `profile_pic` y de ahí avanzar a lo siguiente, que sería borrar la imagen que ya tengo y luego insertar la de la solicitud y después guardarla.

```
    public function update(Profile $profile, Request $request)
    {   
        $profile->update($this->validateProfile($request));

        if (request()->hasFile('profile_pic')) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('profiles/'.$profile->profile_pic);
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('profiles', $request->file('profile_pic'));
            $profile->profile_pic = $path;
            $profile->save();
        }

        return redirect('/profile')->with('edit_profile', 'You\'ve now changed your profile!');
    }
```

Encontré esta respuesta similar pero no me funcionó, la foto antigua sigue sin borrarse:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/254433/152348

Lo único que consigo haciendo `dd` en esta línea es obtener el archivo que actualmente estoy subiendo.

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete('profiles/'.$profile->profile_pic);
dd($profile->profile_pic);
```

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1298 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "warscrub.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/private/var/tmp"
  filename: "phpfQYAeP"
  basename: "phpfQYAeP"
  pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpfQYAeP"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/private/var/tmp/phpfQYAeP"
  aTime: 2021-12-20 17:00:57
  mTime: 2021-12-20 17:00:57
  cTime: 2021-12-20 17:00:57
  inode: 28511032
  size: 313522
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 501
  group: 0
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Por ejemplo, aquí la imagen que subí desde el formulario se llamaba "warscrubs.png", como hacer para conseguir algo como esto?
`profiles/3YAZMjF5k7RKmarD9xIrZWh3JE4tlEbSn0JN1osq.png` este viene siendo el nombre y la ruta real que tiene el último archivo que subí antes de querer actualizar el campo.

Reglas de validación:

```
    protected function validateProfile($request) 
    {
        return $request->validate([
            'full_name' => ['required'],
            'bio'  => ['required'],
            'profile_pic' => ['image', 'nullable'],
            'linkedin_url'  => ['url', 'nullable'],
            'optional' => ['nullable'],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Puedo entender esto pero si muevo el update y lo mando ya que se haya realizo lo del interior del condicional, la imagen no sale de la carpeta temporal..

Comment: Gracias pero sigue sin borrarse :-( La imagen cambia y se guarda bien en la base de datos con la ruta de mi carpeta de ```profiles``` pero la imagen vieja ahi queda.

Comment: Te puedo compartir el repo del proyecto?? Tengo seed y te crearía un usuario sin foto. Lo que pasa es que ya llevo 2 días en esto y no podido dar con bola. =/

Comment: la carpeta profiles esta dentro de la carpeta public?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ahi esta, con eso quedo. la imagen cambia y se borra la antigua. Entiendo lo de cambiar la pregunta, me parece bien para futura referencia pero el problema que siempre tuve era que la ruta no era la correcta ya que nunca se borraba la imagen "original"... pero si pudieras sugerirme que cambiarle a la pregunta con gusto.

Comment: Claro, si prefieres eso a que te acepte una respuesta tuya, pues como quieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este era mi método inicial:

```
    public function update(Profile $profile, Request $request)
    {   
        $profile->update($this->validateProfile($request));

        if (request()->hasFile('profile_pic')) {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete('profiles/'.$profile->profile_pic);
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('profiles', $request->file('profile_pic'));
            $profile->profile_pic = $path;
            $profile->save();
        }

        return redirect('/profile')->with('edit_profile', 'You\'ve now changed your profile!');
    }
```

Al querer eliminar mi archivo la ruta no coincidía en esta línea:

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete('profiles/'.$profile->profile_pic);
```

Se necesita borrar primero lo que haya en el disco (en mi caso usaba el driver `'public'`) y luego tratar de enviar el archivo nuevo.

```
    public function update(Profile $profile, Request $request)
    {           
        $data = $this->validateProfile($request);
        if (request()->hasFile('profile_pic')) {
            Storage::delete($profile->profile_pic);             
            $data['profile_pic'] = Storage::disk('public')->put('profiles', $request->file('profile_pic'));
        }
        $profile->update($data);
        
        return redirect('/profile')->with('edit_profile', 'You\'ve now changed your profile!');
    }
```

---

Otro problema era que no estaba tratando la variable de path como parte del objeto, aunque la ruta aquí estaba bien ya que si podía ver mi imagen reemplazada, y se veía en el front-end.